# Custom Activity at first launch (initialization wizard)

Tags: android, android-intent, wizard, intentfilter

I would like to define my own "SetupWizard" application.
To do so, I am using this intent-filter and it works fine :

```
<intent-filter android:priority="5">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

However I don't know how to tell that the Wizard is over.
For now, it is just looping after my last finish() call.

How can I tell it ?

Tkx.

Comment: Make 2nd activity as your main activity and call SetupWizard activity for the first time

Comment: This is already the case, the Activity receiving the Intent just launches the 2nd Activity

Comment: WHat I said was to make setupwizard as your second activity and launch it only for the first time. i.e dont make it your MAIN activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a custom ROM, I did something like this after setting up the user:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName("com.domain.yourapp", "com.domain.yourapp.SetupWizardActivity"), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```

This is what the CM setup wizard do to disable itself once finished. You need the CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE permission.

My wizard activity has the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: Do we need to push apk to system/apps to make it work?

Comment: Yes, your apk has to be inside of system/app or system/priv-app.

Answer (score 1):

for a custom ROM do the following:
e.g. in your onPause() or any other trigger method do something like:

```
// set DEVICE_PROVISIONED flag because we will end setup wizard and our application.
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEVICE_PROVISIONED, 1);
// enable quicksettings
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.USER_SETUP_COMPLETE, 1);
// remove your activity from package manager
final ComponentName yourActivityCompName = new ComponentName(this, yourSetupWizardClass.class);
final PackageManager packageMngr = getPackageManager();
try {
    packageMngr.setComponentEnabledSetting(yourActivityCompName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException illArgExcp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException: The package name or/and class name you try to remove is not available");
}
finish();
```